# How to obtain Mercury Precession equation $\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+u=a$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, precession

Let $r=R(t)$ and $\theta=\Theta(t)$ describe the orbit of the planet. Define $$u(\theta)\equiv\frac{\bar r}{R[\Theta^{-1}(\theta)]}$$ where $\bar r=5.83\times 10^{12}$ cm be the mean value of the distance between Mercury and the sun. Then $$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+u=a$$ was the equation of the motion, where $a=GM\bar r/h^2$. $M$ is the mass of the sun and $h$ is the angular momentum per unit mass of Mercury, and $a\approx 0.98$.
(Singular perturbation theory by Donald R. Smith)

Could you prove how did the author arrived at the equation of motion, please?

I thought it might be the centripetal acceleration add the gravitational acceleration. However, $$\frac{du}{d\theta}=\bar r  \frac{-1}{R^2[\Theta^{-1}(\theta)]}\frac{dR[\Theta^{-1}(\theta)]}{d\theta}$$.

$$\frac{du}{d\theta}=\bar r  \frac{-1}{R^2[\Theta^{-1}(\theta)]}\frac{dR}{d\theta}[\Theta^{-1}(\theta)]\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{d\Theta}{d\theta}(\Theta^{-1}(\theta))}$$ seemed to be quite complicated, and acting with $\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}$ would lead to $\frac{1}{R^3}$ term.

$$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}=
\bar r  \frac{2}{R^3[t]}\dot R^2 [t]\cdot \frac{1}{\dot \Theta^2(t)}
-\bar r \frac{1}{R^2[t]}\ddot R [t]\cdot \frac{1}{\dot \Theta^2(t)}
+\bar r \frac{1}{R^2[t]}\dot R [t]\cdot \frac{\ddot\Theta(t)}{\dot \Theta^3(t)}$$

- The nice part of this equation was, by adding a small $\epsilon u^2$ perturbation on the right hand side, it translated the Newtonian equation of motion to the relativistic equation of motion.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation

Comment: This is done in very many textbooks.  Marion&Thornton on mechanics comes to mind.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thank you. I immediately recognized it from PM 2Ring's link. I had an incident recently and the thoughts had been a bit fuzzy, the isomorphic map $t=\Theta^{-1}(\theta)$ confused me a bit.